# Screen edge gesture when using UISplitViewController with hidden navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

In an iPhone app, we have the ability to hide the navigation bar. By default, calling `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]` to hide the navigation bar stops the screen edge gesture recognizer `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer` from working, but in the past I could restore this functionality by setting its `delegate` to my own (while the bar is hidden) that does this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return ![otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]];
}
```

However, this doesn't work now that the app is using `UISplitViewController`.

It's unclear if the split view controller is using its own gesture recognizer, or some other issue. I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work.

I can't find any other discussion on this. The most recent posts I've found are years old, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710258/no-swipe-back-when-hiding-navigation-bar-in-uinavigationcontroller?answertab=votes#tab-top), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072876/pop-view-controller-using-screen-edge-pan-gesture-recogniser-not-following-the-t?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854901/uisplitviewcontroller-pan-to-primary-view-from-anywhere).

What am I missing? How can I get a screen edge interactive gesture to work with `UISplitViewController` when the navigation bar is hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you rubber duck.

Of course, soon after posting that, I figured out the answer: when in compact layout, e.g. on iPhone, the `UISplitViewController` has a `UINavigationController` to manage the hierarchy, plus the detail view controller has its own `UINavigationController`.

So the solution was to use the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` of the outer navigation controller (that has multiple view controllers), not the inner one (with only one), thusly:

```
@objc var parentNavigationController: UINavigationController? {
    return navigationController?.parent as? UINavigationController
}
```

I hope this helps someone else encountering this issue.